# DocuSign REST API java sdk with javaee-api 8.0 throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing API integration with docusign using java sdk for REST api. Here is docusign sdk dependency.

```
compile group: 'com.docusign', name: 'docusign-esign-java', version: '3.6.0'
```

My application is running java ee 8.0 container so in my unit test I have dependency.

```
providedCompile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
```

Here is my simple test program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient;
import com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth;

public class DocuSignTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("\nFetching an access token via JWT grant...");

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Only signature scope is needed. Impersonation scope is implied.
        scopes.add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE);
        String privateKey = "loaded-from-properties";
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getBytes();
        
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
        
        apiClient.setOAuthBasePath("https://demo.docusign.net");
        OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken (
                "0dd50ffa-6561-4321-xxxx-39d2738d9e8f",
                "0dd50ffa-6561-1234-yyyy-39d2738d9e8f",
                scopes,
                privateKeyBytes,
                120);
        
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Its throwing following exception while initializing APIClient

```
Fetching an access token via JWT grant...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:171)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.buildHttpClient(ApiClient.java:1375)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.<init>(ApiClient.java:119)
    at com.sunlife.us.dc.esignature.cache.DocuSignTest.main(DocuSignTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:154)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:121)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:196)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes.<clinit>(MediaTypes.java:65)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:111)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:209)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:136)
    ... 16 more
```

Note that if I remove javaee-api dependency it works fine. Looks like docusign sdks need jax-rs 1.1 (jersey 1.19.1) classes but it's conflicting with jax-rs 2.1 classes (in javax.ws.rs package) from javaee-api 8.0 jar. I can not remove this dependency because the code runs under javaee 8.0 container and this dependency is provided by runtime container.

I assume, using docusign java sdk for rest api inside javaee 8.0 container is very normal usecase and there should be a way around this.

Comment: Try running the newer version of the sdk such as 3.7.0-BETA or 3.8.0-BETA which do have support for Jersey2: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java/3.8.0-BETA/jar

Comment: @Frankenmint I tried with 3.7.0-BETA and 3.8.0-BETA and it worked fine with both of these. Thanks. Problem is with only 3.6.0. Do we know when is the next release version coming?

Comment: I believe in the next few weeks it will move from BETA to ga which is considered the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if the [DocuSign example set for Java](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java) works in your dev environment?

Then from there we can see where your app differs. Thank you.